# LDO vs. DC2DC for 3.3V to 1.05V Converting

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, ldo, linear-regulator

I have a reference design that uses an [FP6367S5G 800mA DC2DC converter](https://www.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/pdf/1141778/FITIPOWER/FP6367S5G.html) in the following circuit:

[image]

I have been thinking about the pros and cons for replacing this DC2DC with an LDO.

one of the main differences that I can think of is that the LDO has higher power dissipation, since the LDO transfers the excess power into heat while regulating.
the second important difference is cost.

Is it preferable to replace this circuit with the following LDO-based circuit?

[image]

This is the [data sheet for the RT9186A LDO](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9186A%3DRT9186B/DS9186AB-13.pdf) I want to use.

could be there any complication with this replacement (which I want to do out of cost-related choice)? in addition, I wanted to know how can I decide if the heat that would result of the LDO's bad efficiency can be tolerable or not, and if not, how to deal with that?

Note: the load for this circuit is [VL805 ‧ VL806 - Super Speed USB 3.0 Host Controller](https://www.via-labs.com/product_show.php?id=48), which unfortunately I can't share it's datasheet due to confidentiality concerns.

Comment: That table is both wrong and incomplete; the FP6367 works at 1.5MHz so you are unlikely to hear it, you already have the design so that isn't complex, there is nothing there about ripple, load transient response, etc. But, apart from that, why are you considering replacing it with a linear regulator? As it stands, the question is too broad to answer.

Comment: I want to replace it because the LDO is cheaper and also it's already available at the company that I work in (I can't afford waiting for the order).

Comment: @Andyaka Well, I rephrased the Question.

Comment: @Andyaka, thanks!

Comment: @Andyaka I made some modifications.

Comment: "Is it preferable to replace this circuit with the following LDO-based circuit?" - only you can answer that, since we don't know your preferences.

Comment: "how can I decide if the heat that would result of the LDO's bad efficiency can be tolerable or not" - again, only you can answer that since what I could tolerate in a particular case may be vastly different to what you could tolerate in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Note: the load for this circuit is VL805 ‧ VL806 - Super Speed USB 3.0
> Host Controller, which unfortunately I can't share it's datasheet due
> to confidentiality concerns.*

The main consideration is power dissipation and I have used a figure of 300 mA for the load current. Less or more, the process is the same. It's a guess of course!

The RT9186A has (at best) a thermal resistance of 105°C/watt. So, if the average output current is (say) 300 mA, the power dissipation will be: -

$$\text{300 mA}\cdot\left[\text{3.3 volts - 1.05 volts}\right] = \text{675 mW}$$

This will raise the junction above the case by 71°C for the VDFN-8L device and 108°C for the MSOP device.

If the local ambient temperature is (say) 25°C the junction of the VDFN-8L device will rise to 96°C and, for the MSOP, it will rise to 133°C. Then after a short while, due to localized heating, the local temperature may increase by another 20°C. This means the junction could rise to 116°C or 153°C (device dependent).

The limit is 150°C so, in this simplistic method, you might be concerned about the MSOP part.

Nothing more can really be added without knowledge of the load and that is being kept secret due to confidentiality. You will, I'm sure need to provide significant copper around the part to help with power dissipation but, that's for you to decide.

However, one trick you could use is a dropper resistor feeding the regulator's power supply input. Given that the proposed regulator can work from an input supply voltage of 2.5 volts, the dropper resistor could "lose" (say) 0.6 volts at full current (say 300 mA) and the regulator's power dissipation would reduce from 675 mW to around 495 mW. The resistor would of course dissipate the extra but, it might be a preferable solution.

Comment: thanks Andy! I have a really simple question, how do I really calculate the output current? Intuitively I'd say it's Vout divided by the Load's Impedance, but looking at the datasheet (which I didn't share), I didn't find something that has to do with the relevant pin's impedance that is located at the load. do you have a suggestion for the terms that I should be looking for in the datasheet?

Also, what information do you need from datasheet that I might be able to share without sharing the PDF itself?

Comment: You need to calculate this because without seeing the DS it's guesswork and I don't like guessing. There is nothing generic to say or advise that I can think of.

Comment: I agree with Andy, we can't take assumptions, If you don't have datasheet, may be you can take alternates from other vendors like TI(https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sllse76m/sllse76m.pdf) or Renesas (https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/interface-connectivity/usb-switches-hubs/upd720201-usb-30-host-controller). Take 30% extra load.

Comment: Thanks @user19579, the "ti" datasheet looks quiet similar to that of FP6367S5G. when you say take extra load, that means to choose a regulator that is capable of additional 30% of the current that "ti" xHCI Host Controller for example consumes?

Comment: yes, manufacturers will have variations. we can't take them directly. better to take buffer of 30%, via-labs looks like chineese ---- better to take buffer current....